# Send mail from docker container, host with NGINX and reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nodemailer, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've configured NGINX in a cloud instance with reverse proxy to a docker container. The app sends emails using nodemailer - Gmail SMTP but isn't working inside a docker container.

**My guess:**

- Missing ports configurations
- A mail proxy or something is needed...

I tried exposing ports 587 and 465 in the Dockerfile with no success (Not sure if that's correct or if I need something else).

**Other considerations:**

- The container runs it's own server using Koa.
- The cloud instance will host more containers that may send mail too. Each with their own domain and reverse proxy configurations.

Your help is really appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Running the app in the container: Gmail is giving a 534 response code (invalid login error)
Still working fine runnning the app outside the container.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a docker / nginx problem but more like a app configuration problem. Have you double checked the app configuration inside the container is picked up properly?

Comment: Hi @timsmelik thanks for taking the time to comment. I've been checking the configuration yes, but not sure what should I exactly check. For now I noticed that gmail is giving an invalid login error but only inside the container. I think it's a missing configuration for 587 port. Do you have experience with that?

Comment: You shouldn't have to open ports to reach the Google servers from inside the containers and if there was a routing problem, you probably wouldn't get any response at all. I'm unfamiliar with your app, but you could try logging the Gmail username / password and see if that matches what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail authentication was giving login errors running the app in the container.
The correct way is to configure it through OAuth2 and it works flawlessly.

Here's the tutorial I found that helped me out: https://alexb72.medium.com/how-to-send-emails-using-a-nodemailer-gmail-and-oauth2-fe19d66451f9

Thanks timsmelik for your help.